# Minus function in sql

Tags: sql, function, subtraction

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.caption = 'abc' THEN a.id END) AS "Reject",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.caption ='5' THEN b.id END) AS "Dup"
FROM a with (NOLOCK) left outer join
     b re with (NOLOCK)
     On a.id= b.id
```

I want to get the difference of both the counts in same sql query. When i am using minus function it is giving me error: The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.caption = 'abc' THEN a.id END) AS "Reject",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.caption ='5' THEN b.id END) AS "Dup",
       (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.caption = 'abc' THEN a.id END) -
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.caption ='5' THEN b.id END)
       ) as diff
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b re
     ON a.id = b.id  ;
```

Don't use `WITH (NOLOCK)` unless you really know what you are doing.  You could get inconsistent data.